# Check result of Future[Boolean] to be either true or false

Tags: scala, asynchronous, playframework, future

I have a following function that takes in a `Future[List[BSONDocument]]` and tries to return a `Boolean`. I am using this function to check if the result back from a async DB call is empty or not.

```
def checkExistingMessages(resultFromDB: Future[List[BSONDocument]]): Future[Boolean] = {

    resultFromDB.map { result =>
      if (result.isEmpty) {
        false
      }
      else true
    }

  }
```

However, when I try to do something like this:

```
val result = checkExistingMessages(db.getDocument(name, age))
if (result){
    println("The result is TRUE")
}
```

I get the follwing error:
`Expression of type Future[Boolean] does not conform to expected type Boolean`

**UPDATE 1:**

```
def doesMsgExist(name: String, age: String): Boolean = {
    var result = false
    val msgExistsFlag = checkExistingMessages(db.getDocument(name, age))
    msgExistsFlag.foreach(isTrue => result = if(isTrue) false else true)
    result
  }


  def checkExistingMessages(resultFromDB: Future[List[BSONDocument]]): Future[Boolean] = {

    resultFromDB.map { list =>

      if (list.isEmpty) {
        false
      }
      else true
    }

  }
```

Comment: Because you get Future[Boolean], NOT Boolean. You can try for comprehension for{exists <- result} {println("The result is TRUE")}. If you want to wait for a result, try Await.result(result, Duraton.Inf). But it's bad practice, and don't do this in prod

Comment: @IgorMielientiev: How do I tweak it to get an actual Boolean where I can assert True or False?

Comment: `map` over the future, then you can access the value and check the result.

Comment: @summerNight I've updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have noted, one way to do this is asynchronously, along the lines of:

```
val result: Future[Boolean] = checkExistingMessages(db.getDocument(name, age))
result.foreach(b => if(b) println("the result is true"))
```

Alternatively, to handle the computation synchronously you can do something like the following to turn the `Future[Boolean]` into a plain `Boolean`:

```
val result: Future[Boolean] = checkExistingMessages(db.getDocument(name, age))
val b: Boolean = Await.result(result, scala.concurrent.duration.Duration(5, "seconds"))
```

This will block the main thread for up to 5 seconds while waiting for the Future to complete; if the future completes successfully in that time it will return the value, and otherwise will throw an exception. Then you can use the value like any other Boolean.

Answer (score 2):

`result` is of type `Future[Boolean]` (and not `Boolean`).

So in your case, you can use `foreach` to access the result of the `Future`:

```
result.foreach(b => if(b) println("The result is TRUE"))
```

Comment: Could you please look at my UPDATE 1. I tried to implement a new function on what you recommended but my function `doesMsgExist()` always returns `false`